# Compiling hip code using hipcc -O0 for AMD GPU

Tags: gpu, compiler-optimization, amd, amd-gpu, hip

I'm using AMD RADEON RX7600.

I've been trying to compile HIP code using the precompiled hipcc compiler for a few weeks now.
When compiled with O[1/2/3] everything works fine. When I encountered some bugs, I tried to compile the code with O0 and things stopped working.

When dispatching a kernel I get an error code (401) - which according to the dull documentation means "Invalid state of device" - I have no clue what this means.
I even tried compiling hipcc by myself by using the aomp project but it does not make any difference.

Any ideas?